# control not working properly

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to use the keydown feature .My code is up and running but am getting this strange error.I am running a query where if in the database column value is MIND then the radiobutton mind should be checked else MSSL.but the control always goes into else part no matter ,the value in the database is MIND or MSSL.
Following is my code

```
    private void txtlogin_userid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
     {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
         {
           if (sender is TextBox)
           {
        TextBox txb = (TextBox)sender;
        dc.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from UserMaster where UserID='" + txb.Text + "'", sc);
        dc.Fill(ds);
        dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        txtlogin_name.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
        txtlogin_mailid.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString());
        string a = "MIND";

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString() == a)
        {
            radiomind.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            radioMSSL.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}}
```

when i enter the any number that has MIND as its value in the database,the message box shows MIND but still the control goes into else part and the MSSL radio button activates.what to do?

Comment: In the debugger, do you ever see that the value of `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3]` is "MIND"?

Comment: i have added the messagebox that displays MIND as soon as i enter the value in the textbox and hit enter.

Comment: MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString());

Comment: try using ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString().Equals(a)

Comment: Can we see that textbox code? You're comparing the raw strings. There could be a number of issues there -- trailing spaces in the database, capitalization differences come to mind right off. Add `.Trim().ToUpper()` and see if that helps.

Comment: did tat..still the same result..its activating radiobutton for MSSL but the value is MIND

Comment: is this what u r asking for   public class CustomTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        {
            protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
            {
                if (keyData == Keys.Return)
                    return true;
                return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
            }
        }

Comment: How are your radiobuttons set up? Is there anywhere else in the code that touches either of them? Do they have default values?

Comment: no i have just added them onto the form from toolbox and named them as radiomind and radioMSSL in properties->name.they are not accessed anywhere else

Comment: btw, if this is production code then its vulnerable to sql-injection. Use SqlParameters to avoid this issue. In addition, I'd really recommend using a different tech to access the database. Even typed datasets would be nicer than this.

Comment: you're taking raw input from a textbox and inserting it into an sql command. So if I enter: "0; drop table users --" into the textbox, what do you think might happen? ;)

Comment: then suggest what should i do?the textbox is supposed to take only numerical value.its actually like a employee unique number

Comment: ???i thought you people were going ti suggest

Comment: He did tell you want to do: use `SqlParameter`s: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Put a break point on each of the radio[...].Checked, is it really going into the else? Maybe the radio button variable name are wrong. Maybe the radio button are being reset somewhere else.

```
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString() == a)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("mind");
        radiomind.Checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("mssl");
        radioMSSL.Checked = true;
    }
```

Check the exact value of each strings you are comparing. Do they have extra space, characters? Sometime a string can have an extra white space.

```
MessageBox.Show("[" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString() + "]"); 
MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString().Length); 
MessageBox.Show("[" + a + "]"); 
MessageBox.Show(a.Length);
```

Side note

Like Quibblesome said, you should use [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) cause you are vulnerable to [sql-injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

If you are doing select *, you might have errors in the futur if the order of your columsn changes.

Comment: its showing error in the line MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString().Length);

Comment: @user2707945 capital 'L', I changed it

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
```

instead of `Keys.Enter`.

---

If you write

```
private void txtlogin_userid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyCode);
}
```

You will see the actual code in the Output Window (open with menu: Debug > Windows > Output).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
        Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3]) == a
```

Instead.

Comment: :(...did this..still mssl radio button is activating